# How to use native heap for bitmap on android

Tags: android, bitmap, out-of-memory, heap-memory, native

I would like to load, process and store high resolution image. In spite of `largeHeap="true"` option in `AndroidManifest.xml`, when some high resolution image was loaded, OOM exception was occurred frequently.

By googling, I knew that using JNI can load bitmap to native heap on lower version than Android 3.0. If so, how can I use native heap for bitmap on higher version of it? still JNI?

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, you should decode and process each part of big bitmap instead of process whole the bitmap. It'll help to avoid OOM.
[BitmapRegionDecoder](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/BitmapRegionDecoder.html) can be used to decode a rectangle region from an image. Hope it can help.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. If I use `BitmapRegionDecoder` as you mentioned, I can load and process high resolution image. However I don't know how to assemble each part and save as one file. if you know that way, let me know please.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure that what do you mean by "process", but you could use the following library if you need to load large data and then zoom in to extract more details

https://github.com/davemorrissey/subsampling-scale-image-view